# How to write if condition in mysql in cakephp2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

how can I write  `SELECT IF(1>2,2,3);` in `this->find('all', array())` format in cakephp 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 $data =  $this->Model->find("all", array(
        "fields"     => array("IF( 1 > 2 ,2, 3) AS result"),
        "conditions" => ...
    ));
```

This will give your output in **result** index of your array.

Hope this will help!